# Multiple network interface

Tags: networking

Suppose my laptop is connected to a wifi and is also tethered to a phone. Is it possible to specify which application uses which internet.

in particular is it possible to open two firefox windows using two different internet?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to specify this per application.

However, you can use something called *network namespaces*: You can think of them as "virtual computers", which share the filesystem and everything else except the networking setup.

So you can make, say, a network namespace which contains the network interface tethered to the phone, keep the wifi interface in the main network namespace, and then start a firefox in the main network namespace and another firefox in the newly made namespace.

Each firefox will then only use the appropriate network interface to connect to the internet.

This setup is also great if you want to *monitor* what applications do: You connect up the newly made network namespace to the main network namespace via a *virtual ethernet pair* (veth), setup the main network namespace for forwarding and network address translation (NAT), and then you can listen with `wireshark` etc. to all network traffic from the applications in the namespace.

If you want to play around with network namespaces, have a look at the script in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396175/how-do-i-connect-a-veth-device-inside-an-anonymous-network-namespace-to-one-ou/396193#396193). This script creates a new namespace and connects it up via veth.

For your setup you must modify it to move one network interface into the new namespace, and you don't need the veth.