What is the reason why creating a veth requires root?
I recently became aware of solutions like slirp4netns or passt/pasta which essentially work around the fact that you can't create a pair of veth network interfaces without root (or CAP_NET_ADMIN). Before user namespaces became widely available, changing the network configuration was indeed originally restricted to the superuser.
Is there a documented reason why it was deemed "easier" to create a whole entire TCP/IP stack and/or complex abstraction layers rather than just allowing users to create their own pairs? Was it difficult to implement a user permission scheme on top of the networking configuration tools, or are there security reasons why allowing non-root users to modify the network configuration of interfaces they themselves created would be a bad idea?

I haven't tried it, but should the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability be totally sufficient to create veth network interfaces? (no, it wasn't restricted to the superuser, it was restricted to that user and processes with that capability)

You're right, that may be the case (edited the Q to reflect that). But wouldn't CAP_NET_ADMIN give you broad permission to modify any network interface? That would probably count as a "bad idea" in terms of security, no?

you're on point with it being a bad idea. I think you're overemphasising the security aspect here. It's simply not very useful to have arbitrary many network interfaces with no namespacing. Imagine instead of directories, Linux' file system was flat, and ever user could create files in that one flat list of files. That wouldn't sound like much fun to organize files, right? You'd quickly start to emulate hierarchical things (for example, each file name needs to start with the user name of its owner) to de-clash things.

Good point! I guess a lot of my question remains though: you could imagine letting users create their own veth in their own network namespaces, right? Or is that something that's not currently possible?

I'd say that's a pretty new question and would make a good new question post!

I'll accept the answer then, thanks for taking the time! I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396175/how-do-i-connect-a-veth-device-inside-an-anonymous-network-namespace-to-one-ou that hints at it being possible to connect a veth pair from a network ns inside a user ns to the root ns (host), so I'll try to reformulate a question once I have absorbed that.

Created https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782475/is-it-possible-to-use-a-veth-created-in-a-user-namespace-as-a-regular-user-in-a after some testing


Is there a documented reason why it was deemed "easier" to create a whole entire TCP/IP stack and/or complex abstraction layers rather than just allowing users to create their own pairs? Was it difficult to implement a user permission scheme on top of the networking configuration tools, or are there security reasons why allowing non-root users to modify the network configuration would be a bad idea?

Security is not an afterthought in this, but it's rarely the driving force in features. A lot of security folks forget that we don't do computing to make it secure, but to actually compute things. It'd be more secure to just not compute at all!
So, this is primarily a compartimentalization feature, more than an isolation fence.
First of all, you're wrong about the "having to be root" aspect; that's what capabilities are for, see man 7 capabilities for more details!
Then:
It seems to me that if you allow every user to create network devices when there's only one global space where they all end up in, with one global set of tables of firewall rules and so on, you're setting yourself up for an immense amount of chaos. Make the network devices that a set of processes see containable in a logical construct, and you can suddenly do sensible things like having your set of file server processes work with the dedicated SAN network interface, whereas the control pane talks to these over an internal network (that's not just the one global loopback interface, but allows for different virtual endpoints, using different addresses), and has listeners on the control network, while the system controller keeps watch over all this and reconnects the control pane to a cellular uplink if network goes down.
This "logical construct" to combine network devices, their routing- and firewall rules into one logical entity is what a network namespace is.
It has the added benefit of the file server process not getting access to the management interface, but when network namespaces were invented, a lot of network services had to run as root anyways, so that was an isolation that was trivial to escape, anyways, as trivial as figuring out how to open a socket on a different host interface, anyways.
